# automatic silent provisioning and activation of our users in Docusign, via Salesforce

Tags: docusignapi

We used JWT to create users automatically in Docusign, from Salesforce - this is working fine, the users are getting created in Docusign. We have claimed the email domains.

However, when these users try and generate documents (DocGen) or use eSignature (as themselves) they are asked to authenticate (we used the DocGen and eSignature managed packages). The users don't know their login credentials because the automatic provisioning process is supposed to activate their accounts automatically using the DS admin user of the account/organisation and/or with the integration key which has been setup with the following scopes - "organization_read group_read permission_read user_read user_write account_read domain_read identity_provider_read signature impersonation".

Any tips on how to get past this? We don't have SSO setup with Docusign (identity provider)?

Answer (score 0):

Once the user_id being used to make the JWT calls was given full admin access it all worked fine and silent activation took place

Now when the new user logins to SF and tries to generate a new document (doc gen) or send a new document (eSignature) they are asked to 'Authorize' and consent the first time - there is no need for them to login.